# Error on linking email addresses inside elsarticle template

Tags: hyperref, elsarticle

I am perplexed by the error:

```
 Use of \@uad doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.11 ...iversity.edu}{mailto:a2@myuniversity.edu}}
```

Arising in the following minimal tex file using the standard elsarticle class:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Remarks on something interesting}

\author[myu]{Author 1}
\ead{a1@myuniversity.edu}

\author[myu]{Author 2 \corref{cor1}}
\ead{\href{mailto:a2@myuniversity.edu}{mailto:a2@myuniversity.edu}}

\address[myu]{My Department, My Building, My University in My City}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\end{frontmatter}

\maketitle

A \href{http://google.com}{link to google.com}

\end{document}
```

It looks as though the class file doesn't support `\href` arguments here, but it is not obvious to me why that is.  So, I'm left with several questions:

1. What does this error mean?
2. How I might go about modifying either the `.tex` or the `.cls` file so that the above can be compiled successfully?

I've taken a look at where `\ead` is defined in the class field but lack the tex-foo to figure out what's going on. I believe the relevant lines are:

```
\def\ead{\@ifnextchar[{\@uad}{\@ead}}
\gdef\@ead#1{\bgroup\def\_{\string\_}\def\{{\string\{}%
   \def\}{\string\}}%
   \edef\tmp{\the\@eadauthor}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\emailauthor
     {#1}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmp}}%
  \egroup
}
```

The error seems like it might be related to how and where tex defines macros, but that is a bit over my head.

**Background**: Not directly relevant to this question, but sometimes context is useful. I encounter this when trying to use the elsarticle template in RStudio's rmarkdown, which uses pandoc with the option `autolink_bare_uris` which apparently cannot be turned off.  This forces pandoc to transform bare emails into `href`'d ones, rather annoyingly breaking this template.

Comment: Seems that you should simply use `\ead{a2@myuniversity.edu}` instead of putting `\href` inside `\ead`.

Comment: @KevinC Yes, I realize that works but that's not my question. (I cannot do that for reasons I give in the background, and besides I would prefer it linked).  My question is how to modify the cls file such that this works *with* the `\href` inside `\ead`.  Given the flexibility of TeX it seems that should not be impossible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\ead` command in `elsarticle` writes the `\emailauthor` command to the `aux` file with the passed email address and the associated author as arguments. On subsequent runs, the `aux` file is read and the `\emailauthor` command is executed. The issue with adding `\href` as you have tried is that the `\immediate\write\@auxout` tries to expand it prior to writing the contents to the `aux` file, resulting in the error. As we want `\href` to be written to the `aux` file, you can do what you are after by prefacing `\href` with `\string` or `\noexpand`. For example:

```
\ead{\string\href{mailto:a2@myuniversity.edu}{a2@myuniversity.edu}}
```

You can check the `aux` file to see the following line (as expected):

```
\emailauthor{\href{mailto:a2@myuniversity.edu}{a2@myuniversity.edu}}{Author 2 \corref {cor1}}
```

Additionally, you can automate hyperlinking for all author emails and urls by modifying `\@ead` and `\@uad`, repsectively, with the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter%placed AFTER \usepackage{hyperref}, if to be used
    \newif\ifhyperrefloaded\hyperrefloadedfalse
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hyperrefloadedtrue}{\hyperrefloadedfalse}%check if hyperref is loaded
    \ifhyperrefloaded%
        \patchcmd{\@ead}{#1}{\string\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}{}{}
        \patchcmd{\@uad}{#2}{\string\url{#2}}{}{}\fi
\makeatother
```

The `\ifhyperrefloaded` is used to so that the `\patchcmd` calls are in the global scope and only used if the `hyperref` package is loaded.

Finally, I took the liberty of removing the `mailto:` from the displayed portion of `\href` and the unnecessary `\maketitle` from your MWE.

The result:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter%placed AFTER \usepackage{hyperref}, if to be used
    \newif\ifhyperrefloaded\hyperrefloadedfalse
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hyperrefloadedtrue}{\hyperrefloadedfalse}%check if hyperref is loaded
    \ifhyperrefloaded%
        \patchcmd{\@ead}{#1}{\string\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}{}{}
        \patchcmd{\@uad}{#2}{\string\url{#2}}{}{}\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Remarks on something interesting}

\author[myu]{Author 1}
\ead{a1@myuniversity.edu}

\author[myu]{Author 2 \corref{cor1}}
\ead{a2@myuniversity.edu}
\ead[url]{www.google.com}

\address[myu]{My Department, My Building, My University in My City}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\end{frontmatter}

A \href{http://google.com}{link to google.com}

\end{document}
```

[image: linked email and url]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to not work with version 3.3 of elsarticle.cls.
I was able to produce the expected behavior via redifining both\emailauthor and \urlauthor, though:

```
\makeatletter
% ead[url] with a hyperlink
\gdef\urlauthor#1#2{\g@addto@macro\@elsuads{\let\corref\@gobble%
     \def\@@tmp{#1}\raggedright\eadsep
     {\ttfamily\url{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@@tmp}}\space(#2)%
     \def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
% ead with a mailto:
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2{\stepcounter{ead}%
     \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
      \let\corref\@gobble\def\@@tmp{#1}%
      \eadsep{\ttfamily\href{mailto:\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@@tmp}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@@tmp}}
      (#2)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!